# Google Firebase Cloud Functions: Error: Your project is being set up. Please wait a minute before deploying again

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deployment, google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a Google Cloud / Firebase project, let's call it A, to which I can normally deploy Cloud Functions via the `firebase deploy` command.

Recently I've had to set up a parallel project that is supposed to run the same functions, just with a separate database, so I set up a second project, let's call it B, to which I thought I'd be able to deploy Functions in the same way, after setting up all the required services.

In fact, the first time that I deployed the functions to project B, it worked, and those functions are working fine.

Now however I need to deploy a new version of the functions, and deploying to project A still works normally, however deploying to project B via `firebase deploy` raises the following error:

```
=== Deploying to 'B'...

i  deploying storage, firestore, functions


There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.

Error: Your project is being set up. Please wait a minute before deploying again.
```

Google App Engine is set up in the same way on projects A and B. Of course I have waited much longer than one minute, I've been trying for some days as a matter of fact.

I suppose I could rewrite the code to deploy via the `gcloud` command, but it feels like unnecessary work since the `firebase` command still deploys normally to the original project.

This is probably some misconfiguration on the server side, but everything appears the same to me between the two projects. Does anyone have an idea how to debug this?

Environment:

- Google Cloud SDK 435.0.1
- Node 18.16.0
- firebase-tools 12.4.0
- firebase-admin 11.9.0
- firebase-functions 4.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a similar problem, in our case, the issue was that we didn't initialize the Storage Bucket in our Project B, so `firebase deploy` failed while trying to upload our `storage.rules` file. Have you made sure that you have initialized everything that you need in your Project B?

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin :) Unfortunately in my case all storage buckets are initialized, including the GAE default bucket. One difference that I noticed is that project B does not have a service-#######@gcp-gae-service.iam.gserviceaccount.com service account with the "App Engine Standard Environment Service Agent" role, which instead on project A has a permission to the GAE default bucket. I'm also in contact with the Firebase support, hopefully I'll resolve that way, and in that case I'll post the answer.

Comment: Update: I deployed a dummy GAE app (this project only uses Cloud Functions), which created the missing account service and even added it to the GAE default bucket, however `firebase deploy` still fails with the same error.

Comment: Apologies Kevin, I misunderstood your answer, also because the error message misled me to think that the problem was related to the App Engine, so I was looking at the Cloud Console, instead you were referring to the Firebase Console, specifically https://console.firebase.google.com/project/<PROJECT_ID>/storage , and indeed the problem was that I hadn't initialized the default storage bucket there! So thank you, you solved my problem :)

Answer (score -1):

This one resolved my case

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```